# flex box not getting full height with flex-wrap

Tags: css, flexbox

I have created a simple JSFiddle below. Why is it that my pink box (`.screen`) isn't growing to the full height all the way up to the red and blue boxes?

I have tried to set `height: 100%` on the `screen` div but that makes it grow out-of the the `.inner-container` and placing itself above the `.bottom`.

**EDIT**
I have an issue with putting `.screen` outside of `.inner-container` that I forgot to tell about. When the page is first initialized the `.screen` will have a `display:none` because the user has not started screen-sharing. When the user clicks the button to share his screen I will set `.subscriber` to `width: 10rem` and `.screen` will be displayed. By just using width I can then "move" the subscriber container from the middle up to the top.

**EDIT 2**
To more show what I'm after you can remove the `flex: 0 1 100%` from `.screen` and add `width: 100%; height: calc(100% - 10.5rem);`. This just feels like I should be able to do with flex but maybe not.

**Solution**
I ended up moving the `.screen` outside of `.inner-container` and I'm dynamically switching the flex-direction between `row` and `column` on `.inner-container` to get the desired outcome. See @vals answer on why this is not possible using flex-box right now.

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kejq01s2/2/

```css
.outer-container {
  height: 100vh;
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.inner-container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.publisher {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background: red;
  margin: .5rem;
}

.subscriber {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background: blue;
  margin: .5rem;
}

.screen {
  background: pink;
  flex: 0 1 100%;
}

.bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 6rem;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="publisher"></div>
    <div class="subscriber"></div>
    <div class="screen"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to make the screen outside the inner-container

Comment: @TemaniAfif I have updated my question. Need to have all three divs inside of ```.inner-container``` so I can dynamically move around objects.

Comment: You're not factoring in the effect of `align-content: stretch`, a default setting on flex containers. See the duplicate posts for an explanation.

Comment: Also, set a height on the pink item, because without height or content, it can shrink to 0 height.

Comment: @Michael_B I reopened this question. I don't think that using align-content or align-self is the solution for this problem. I had already tried them, without succes. At the moment, I don't think this is achievable using flex. (would like to be proved wrong)

Comment: @vals, Maybe I misunderstood the question, but I thought `align-content` explained the problem.

Comment: @Michael_B I have added an answer explaining what is the problem, as I understand it

Comment: @vals thanks for your help. Updated my post with how I solved my problem using flexbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an answer to show you how to achieve this, but an explainer of what is happening, and why you can not get what you want.

Since the flex-direction is *row*, the height is the **cross-axis**. You can control this size with 2 styles, **align-items** and **align-content**

If you set align-items to *stretch*, then the items will grow ... until they reach the flex-line height. (The flex container sets the items in lines, even though those are not visible).

If you set align-content to *stretch*, then the flex-lines will grow to fill all available space in the container.

Now, in your layout, **screen**  has no height. So, when the flex-lines are dimensioned, the first line gets the height of about 11em , the publisher height. The second line gets a height of 0. Setting align-content to stretch will make the flex-lines grow until they fill all available space in the container.

**BUT**, the extra space  will be distributed equally between the first and the second line. So, the second line can not grow to fit the perceived height of the first line.

You can set the *screen* element to grow individually, that is done with a variant of align-items that is align-self, this one is set at the children instead of the parent, so it is selective. BUT, you don't have a property to decide which flex-line grows, so you are out of luck.

May be you could get this layout to work with css-grids, but I don't know all the requirements of your case to be sure about this.